# Accessing specific key and its value in a object returned from firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, key, key-value

I have a JS function which goes into a Firebase realtime database to read some objects. The objects it checks have several fields but I only want one of these, the URL key and its value. Here is my function which retrieves the data:

```
const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref('gifs');
dbRefObject.on('value', gotData);

function gotData(data){
    dbRefObject.once('value', function(snapshot){
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){
            var childKey = childSnapshot.key;
            var childData = childSnapshot.val();
            console.log(childKey, "   ", childData);
            })
        }
    ) 
}
```

The data that is actually returned looks like this:

```
Content Description: "Hack The Planet"
Date Added: "08/04/2020"
Permission: "Admin"
URL: "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/..."
```

I only want to access the URL key and its data but I cant seem to do so. I have tried doing childData[3] but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Child values in Realtime Database are always specified by their name, not by their order.  To get the URL from the snapshot, you will want to use:

```
var childData = childSnapshot.val();
var URL = childData.URL;
```

Note that the names of the children become the keys of the object returned by `val()`.

Comment: Thank you! Didnt expect it to be as simple as that